# Is there a way to reference keys in plist file 1 from plist file 2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

I have a Plist 1 setup like this:

```
Root
    EquipmentSlide1             Dictionary
        baseImage               String
        customImageLocation     Array
            Item 0              String
            Item 1              String
     EquipmentSlide2          Dictionary
        baseImage               String
        customImageLocation     Array
            Item 0              String
            Item 1              String
```

I have Plist 2 setup like this:

```
Root
     EquipmentDeck1             Array        
        Item 0                  Dictionary     EquipmentSlide1
```

So what I would like to do is set the value in Plist 2 for Item 0 to be the Dictionary object at EquipmentSlide1 in Plist 1.  Like a linked list?  Is it possible to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. A plist is just a file format. You have two options:

1. Combine two files into a single file
2. Create a convention for yourself to be able to reference the other file and write custom code to load the two files in simultaneously

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the inputs here.  I came up with a way to handle this that works.  I load my "master" plist into a custom data object when the app loads in the appdelegate.  The master plist holds dictionary objects that describe all the images avaiable for use in the custom slide deck the app is building.  Once the user answers the questionare and I get a result, I load other plist's that hold "references" to specific objects in the master plist.  The  specific references depend on the questionare result.  Its a little confusing but works...   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done once you load the two plists into arrays. You will have to make the array (and its sub-arrays) of the 2nd plist be mutable. Then you will need to iterate through the arrays and add the proper dictionary from the 1st array into the proper location within the array structure for the 2nd plist.

BTW - all of this is kind of pointless. Why not just combine the two plists into one?

Answer (score 0):

Drewag and Rmaddy are right.

Precisely, it's XML format file that is stored in the NSBundle. Apple does not provide it in an advanced way so that it can only store immutable, fundamental classes like NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary. Because of its limitation, most of the programmers will use it for store and retrieve user's setting. Nevertheless, frequent use data will also be stored in the plist like zip code in United States. So, if your propose is beyond these two. I suggest that you should find another way to implement it.